# WPF & MVVM - ViewModels and DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Using the MVVM pattern in WPF, is it best to use a 'master' ViewModel and only use that as your DataContext or is it okay to have multiple ViewModels that interact with the view (if that's possible)? Sorry if this is a dumb question; I'm very new to MVVM.

Comment: Yes, usually there is a hierarchical relationship between ViewModels. That's OK. That relationship should reflect the logical relationship between the Views.

Comment: MVVM Light uses the [service locator pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx) to assign DataContext.

Comment: Typically I lean towards having a single ViewModel correspond to a single XAML view file.  It's perfectly acceptable for a view to have child views (UserControls), and have corresponding child ViewModels however it really depends on your situation.  Unfortunately, while your question certainly isn't dumb by any means, it's a bit too vague to be answerable (the only answer is "it depends") and will likely be closed as a result.  A better worded example might be, "Here's a specific example of what I'm doing and the problem it poses, how could I achieve my goal of x and resolve my problem of y?"

Comment: Even if it's closed I think you guys have answered it well enough. Also, Romoku mentioned MVVM Light. Right now I'm using the framework found in this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

How does the full version of MicroMVVM stand up to MVVM Light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "one way rules all" approach, but you'll usually see a 1-1 relationship between views and view-models.  In other words, one view-model for a view and this view-model is the data-context for the view.  It's common to see a "base" view-model that inherited by the other view-models.  This is a very simple explanation, but probably a good starting point for a beginner.